# Converting image from post request to image in vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am handling a post request coming from the server that has a binary data as return.

[image]

I am trying to convert it to blob and showing it in my code.

```
api.post('my api server here ', { url: e })
    .then(response => {
      try {
        // Check if the response is valid and contains data
        if (response.data) {
          const binaryData = response.data; // Use response.data directly
          const blob = new Blob([binaryData], { type: 'image/png' });
          const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          // Use imageUrl to display the image
        } else {
          console.error('API response data is empty.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating Blob:', error);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('API request failed:', error);
    });
```

But what I got when click on the link is a broken image icon

[image]

Is there error in my code?

I don't know if it would help but here is the sample binary

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LRYE-pho6Aoq4CUqE2kszO4OcQeUgleACxL8IeeFyKs/edit?usp=sharing

The image file is in .png format. I made sure of it.

Comment: `// Use imageUrl to display the image` is a comment, it doesn't actually do anything - `here is the sample binary link` - that links to a web page, not an image

Comment: Yeah, I just use debugger to get the content of imageUrl which is a link. And that links goes to the broken image. The binary sample link is contains the binary data that was sent from the api

Comment: that may well be but you're still not doing anything with `imageUrl`

Comment: You're just missing `responseType: "blob"` and you don't need to wrap the data in the `Blob()` constructor, it will already be a blob